# If function: Multiple required conditions - either continue or stop Node continuing with the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I am looking to do an initial check on two conditions before I continue executing my code below. If no match is returned for both I want Node.js to stop any further processing. Not sure whether I should wrap my main code within the if function or just leave this as a check at the header of the code.

```
myValue = 500;
nameLow = "lato";
customerValue = 450;

// Initial check
if (nameLow == 'georgia' && myValue >= customervalue) {
    // Continue executing the code within or other code outside of if function
} else {
    // make Node.js stop executing and close
}

// Main code below (only executed when both conditions match
```

I am unsure whether to use return, continue, break and exitprocess() in these instances

Also, how could this be done better with a ternary statement?

Comment: Depends where this code is. `Return` is for a function or global scope and stops further execution (while still doing what it was doing before, ie intervals, event listeners, etc). `Continue` is in a loop to go to next iteration, `break` in a loop to exit the loop, `process.exit()` to completely stop the process. You will most likely find better doc on Google.

Comment: How does this code run? Node will exit naturally once there's nothing to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit ([process.exit](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code)) if the complement is true:

```
if ( nameLow != 'georgia' || myValue < customervalue ) {
    process.exit(1);
}

// Main code below (only executed if nameLow == 'georgia' && myValue >= customervalue)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, Should this not be && as both conditions need to be met or not met with != and what about if the myValue and customervalue are exactly the same? No else option required either?

Comment: @Gracie No, this says to exit if either `nameLow` is not 'georgia' *or* `myValue < customervalue`. That's equivalent to saying continue only if `nameLow` is 'georgia' *and* `myValue >= customervalue`

Comment: @Gracie, it's an application of DeMorgan's rule

Comment: The reason for negating the condition is so that you can just put the exceptional logic (exiting) in the if statement and the rest of your code can be back at normal indentation.